# How to make console and tree "unpinned"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

I want to simulate behavior of WebStorm: when I set console as "Dock Unpinned" it closes if it loses focus. I can press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, that switches focus to editor, and the console is closing. The same with the project tree (or "Explorer" in VS Code).

How to copy this behavior?

[image]

Comment: There is no built-in functionality in vscode to do this.  Perhaps a macro could do this - minimize the terminal/explorer when switching focus to the editor.  Do you want to see that?

Comment: @Mark yes, why not? if it looks similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give these keybindings a try:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+`",
 "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel",
  "when": "panelFocus || editorFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+`",
  "command": "workbench.action.maximizeEditor",
  "when": "sideBarFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+`",
  "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
},
```

I tried to make various combinations work with <kbd>esc</kbd> but there are just too many terminal conflicts with the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backtick</kbd> is interesting since it usually works to toggle the terminal.  You don't necessarily need that last disabled keybinding but with `toggleTerminal` disabled <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backtick</kbd> will return you to whichever view in the Panel you were working on previously - like Search, Problems, etc. instead of only to the terminal.

[image: toggle explorer and terminal]

---

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for waiting.
I tried this, but I had some issues with it. 
1) ctrl + shift + e does not work on linux, so I changed the hot key for explorer to alt + e.

2) when I press ant + e when explorer is in focus - the focus just switching to editor without closing the explorer.

3) when the focus is not on the editor (terminal for example), clicking on the editor doesn't close this (terminal). is it possible to close this (terminal or explorer) after losing focus?

Comment: First, I suggest you copy the code I showed with that keybinding just to see if it works.  Second, "I changed the hot key for explorer to alt + e.": I don't know what this means - the keybindings are really meant to be used as a group.  Did you change the two keybindings to `Alt+E`?  I'll investigate a little more later today.

Comment: It is not possible to close the terminal or explorer just by "clicking" on an editor.  With the keybindingd I showed (or alt+e) when the terminal or explorer has focus and you hit alt+e for example the terminal/explorer will close and focus shift to the current editor.  But you have to use some keybinding  to do change focus and close the terminal/panel.  It can't be done - without an extension - by simply changing focus unless that focus change is accomplished by a keybinding.

Comment: it's not implemented, but there are plugins for that?

Comment: I don't know of any such extension.